# How to compute $\Delta_x \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{|x-y|^2}$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

$\newcommand{\grad}{\operatorname{grad}}$$x$ and $y$ are $n^\text{th}$ dimensional vectors such that $|y|=R$, $|x|<R$ and $\Delta_x$ is a Laplacian operator with respect to vector $x$. i.e., $\Delta_x=\operatorname{div}_x (\grad_x)$. then,

$$\Delta_x \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{|x-y|^2}=0$$

from the fact that $\grad_x|x|=\frac{x}{|x|}$, I have $$\grad_x \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{|x-y|^2}=-2|x-y|^{-2}-2|x-y|^{-4}(R^2-|x|^2)(x-y)$$

and from this, I compute $\grad_x(\grad_x)$ so that I can just sum the components to get divergence:

$$\grad_x\left(\grad_x \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{|x-y|^2}\right)=-2|x-y|^{-2}+8x|x-y|^{-4}(x-y)+6(R^2-|x|^2)|x-y|^{-4}$$

$$=[-2|x-y|^2+8x\cdot(x-y)+6(R^2-|x|^2)]|x-y|^{-4}$$

$$=(4R^2-10x\cdot y)|x-y|^{-4}$$

here $\cdot$  means the inner product. and according to my computation, it seems not $0$ because it became a scalar, so if I sum of them I only get a multiplier $n$.

I did mistake somewhere definitely but I don't know where it is.

Comment: I forgot to mention this: this is Poissin kernel if divided by some $n$ related constant.

Comment: Does the  $y$ vector depend on $x$,  or is it just a constant for the purposes of differentiation?